# Win XP can't connect to Azure App Service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure App Service with which Windows Services communicate using HTTPS.

Since the beginning of May'17 no Windows Service on Windows XP or Windows 2003 can communicate with my server.

I've run test on https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ and I see, that my Azure App Service server closes connection for "IE 6 / XP" and "IE 8 / XP" due to "no SNI" and "no FS"

My question is: has anything changed recently on Azure App Service and if yes, then is it something I can reconfigure, to allow those connections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but what really bothers me is if anything has changed since May on Azure, that lead to my problems.

According to [this article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/6530d35a-9321-4e61-a496-39b66c63a1a0/we-are-updating-our-tlsssl-cipher-suites-to-improve-security?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview), Azure Web App has updated the TLS/SSL cipher suites to improve security at the end of April. The new cipher suite order removed the 3DES cipher which is required by Windows XP to use forward secrecy.

After that, both RC4([RC4 was removed at 2016/04](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-services-ssl-tls-cipher-suite-update-and-removal-of-rc4/)) and 3DES are not supported by Azure Web App. This leads to that we can't communicate with our web server hosted on Azure Web App using HTTPS.

*From the reference article : Note that this change has not been made live yet, it will be rolled out over four weeks starting April 3, 2017.*

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't find it myself. I didn't received any email regarding this change though. The last email about TSL/SSL security upgrade is from June 2015. Not cool Azure, not cool.

Answer (score 0):

SNI most likely is Server Name Indication, part of TLS. That's indeed expected with HTTPS. It's not as ancient as HTTPS itself, which explains why obsolete OS'es like XP do support HTTPS but not SNI.

The insecure equivalent of SNI is "virtual hosting", which is supported by XP. So you just need to downgrade to plain old HTTP/1.1. Of course, you have to be very careful to do this only for clients that are insecure to begin with, else you open up the backdoor even for secure clients. And you probably should get the Legal department involved, to get liability waivers drafted. (but that's getting off-topic)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm aware, that I could force HTTP communication on those problematic clients that still use XP, but what really bothers me is if anything has changed since May on Azure, that lead to my problems.

Comment: @MaciejJakubczyk: Not XP, but Vista support just ended, and I think IE8 with it.